# App serverice deploy fails from vsts 4294967295

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure App Service Deploy to publish from a vsts build. The Azure subscription and App services name was selected from a drop down.

'MySite.scm.MyDomain.net' is happening behind the scenes as I am not using that anywhere in the build. I assume that the build is gathering the information from the selected App service name.

Any thoughts on what might be creating this problem or how to fix it?
Thanks.

```
2017-09-19T17:28:03.5450487Z Got connection details for Azure App Service:'MySite'

2017-09-19T17:28:04.6242199Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:IisApp='d:\a\3\a\AZR-SMTPWS-CRR\20170919.6\' -dest:iisApp='MySite',ComputerName='https://MySite.scm.MyDomain.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=MySite',UserName='********',Password='********',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_222220....

2017-09-19T17:28:05.3040153Z Info: Using ID 'guid' for connections to the remote server.

2017-09-19T17:28:05.5632720Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.

2017-09-19T17:28:05.5632720Z ##[error]Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID
More Information:  Could not connect to the remote computer ("MySite.scm.MyDomain.net"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID.
Error: The remote name could not be resolved: 'MySite.scm.MyDomain.net'
Error count: 1.

2017-09-19T17:28:05.5642718Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295

2017-09-19T17:28:05.5712722Z ##[warning]Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND MySite.scm.MyDomain.net MySite.scm.MyDomain.net:443

2017-09-19T17:28:05.5792694Z ##[section]Finishing: WS Azure App Service Deploy
```

Comment: First, please make sure you can access to `https://MySite.scm.MyDomain.net`. If you can access to the URL, please set `system.debug` = `true` in Variables Tab, and show the detail logs here.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this issue is still happened. I just got this error and came here looking for a fix.

I tried to run the release again (the same release pipeline) but that did not work. Went back to the build pipeline, created a new build pipeline (which was already successfull, and I believe it was the same with you as well. build happens just fine) and then did a new release.

the deployment went just fine.