# Error:C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have setup the VSTS release definition with Dev and Test environments, those  environments successfully deployed without any issue from last 2 months but suddenly today I faced some issue in Test environment even Dev environment succeeded.

The issue like “Error:C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295”, if you want more information see the below screenshot.
[image]

Before posting question I read so many answers and tried with some options like adding -retryInterval: 6000 -retryAttempts:10 and tick the Take app offline option under Additional Deployment Options of VSTS release steps. But those are not helpful for resolving my issue.

So, can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue as soon as possible?

Comment: Is there something different about the test environment? Can you edit the release and revalidate the configuration of the deployment info to the slot you are deploying it? Maybe it needs to reauthenticate it

Comment: No, Test environment is similar to Dev environment only. there is no difference.

Comment: Now  My will be resolved by restarting the my azure app service. but I didn't know exact solution for this issue.

Comment: You can add system.debug variable with true value, then start release and check detail log. Could you reproduce this issue with a new azure app service?

Comment: @starain-MSFT, I tried by setting system.debug variable with true value. But it can't reproduce the issue with new azure app service.

Comment: Maybe something error in azure web app Test environment, restarting it fix the error.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I restarted my web app then the error is gone. But the same error occurred randomly, can you please tell me what is the main issue in azure web app.

Comment: Does the error occurred randomly when deploy app or just access app through internet explorer?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, The above error occurred few times when ever I  was deployed app through the VSTS release.

Comment: Are there error logs of web app deployment in azure?

Comment: I mean the logs of web app in azure. On the other hand, what's the result if you deploy it manually?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT,  This is the link for VSTS release logs of web app deployment https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CwQ9vO2bZ2FMAv2MW

Comment: Check Activity log in azure (Log in azure portal>select the app service>active log)

Comment: I checked in my azure app service activity logs in that there is no logs related to Critical and Error from last one month on words.

Comment: I am facing same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306755/app-serverice-deploy-fails-from-vsts-4294967295

Answer (score 1):

This issue was related to permissions. The IIS deployment needs permissions to override files and do file transform if you have a web.config file.

I had an Azure Pipeline running on a server and I've added the "NETWORK SERVICE" account to the security with full control.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since setting system.debug release definition variable (in variables tab) to true didn't give more information, I finally deleted and recreated the staging slot to be able to deploy again. Of course I checked that the slot app and all its web jobs were stopped.

You're lucky if you deploy to a slot.